# If the second derivatives $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ exist, does $f_{xy}$ exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If the second derivative with respect to to $x$ exists ($f_{xx}$) and the second derivative with respect to $y$ ($f_{yy}$), does it follow that $f_{xy}$ exists?

Comment: Do you want the derivative to exist over the whole domain or just at a point?

Comment: Just one pointt

Comment: Try to adapt the example given at your other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer is

- **Yes**, if the second derivatives  $\:f_{xx} $ and $ \:f_{yy}$  are continuous, and
- **No** (not necessarily), if $\:f_{xx} $ and $ \:f_{yy}$ are discontinuous.

---

For your specific case some clarification is required.

If by saying *"second derivatives $\:f_{xx} $ and $ \:f_{yy}$ exist at a point $P$"*  you mean that the corresponding right and left limits exist and are *equal*, i.e. for a point $P = (x,y)$

$$
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f_x(x + \Delta x,y) - f_x(x , y)}{\Delta x} = 
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f_x(x,y) - f_x(x - \Delta x, y)}{\Delta x} 
\tag{1a}
$$
and
$$
\lim\limits_{\Delta y \to 0} \dfrac{f_y(x,y + \Delta y) - f_y(x , y)}{\Delta y} = 
\lim\limits_{\Delta y \to 0} \dfrac{f_y(x,y) - f_y(x, y - \Delta y)}{\Delta y},
\tag{1b}
$$
then **YES**, $\ f_{xy}$ exists, as conditions $ \eqref{1a}$ and $ \eqref{1b} $ imply that $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ are continuous at $P$.

---

Proving **first case** is not difficult. One write something like

> For any function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with continuous second partial derivatives at a point $P = (x,y)$ we have $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$  ([Schwartz-Clairaut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem)). That means that the order in which you differentiate with respect to different variables does not matter. The existence and continuity of $f_{yy}$ implies that you can differentiate function $f$ at least once w.r.t. $y$ and preserve continuity. Similarly, we conclude that we can differentiate $f$ at least once w.r.t. $x$ and preserve continuity. These two operations are independent, so the result of applying both of them to $f$ will still be continuous, i.e. the corresponding right and left limits exist and are equal. That means that $f_{xy}$ exists and is continuous at the point $P$.

As for the **second case**, we can provide a counterexample. For instance, assume $P = (0,0)$ and consider function

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} & \text{for } \ (x,y) \neq P,\\
(0,0) & \text{for } \ (x,y) = P.
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly $f$ is continuous at $P=(0,0)$, but its second partial derivatives are not.